# How to delete words sum(total) in my view blade template

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, object, laravel-blade

```
$cek = DB::table('temp_obat')
            ->selectRaw('sum(total)')
            ->where('pasien', $id)
            ->get();
$total = $cek;

return view ('buy/bayar',compact('pasien'));
```

[image]

How can I delete the words `sum(total)` in my view blade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```php
$cek = DB::table('temp_obat')
        ->selectRaw('sum(total) as total')
        ->where('pasien', $id)
        ->get();

return view ('buy/bayar', ['cek', $cek]);
```

And in the template:

```
{{ $cek->total }}
```